# Laravel multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I was trying to get list of foods which are in cart as well as favorites table.
I used the following Query to access it. In Conditional Clauses section i wanted to check if the food is in favorites table it also shows or if it's in  carts table also will be shown. But it can't check inside the where clause means the foods id is in the carts table but not in that user. So it should return cart_id as null but it shows cart_id though that user didn't add into his carts table. Same happened in favorites table. How can i make it correct?

```
$foods = DB::table('foods')
             ->leftjoin('carts','carts.food_id','foods.id')
             ->leftjoin('favorites','favorites.food_id','foods.id')
             ->select('foods.food_name', DB::raw('carts.id as cart_id'),DB::raw('favorites.id as favorite_id'),'foods.id','foods.display_image','foods.price','foods.category_id','foods.description','foods.restaurant_id' )
             ->where('foods.restaurant_id','=',$request->Input(['restaurant_id']))    
                ->orwhere(function ($query) {
                            $query->where('carts.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                                  ->where('favorites.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id);
                    })  

               ->get();
```

Comment: I don't know what are you asking, but you really should learn eloquent.

Comment: Can you please post the database tables and Laravel models  are you using for it?

Comment: So you want to get the foods having specific restaurant_id, and must be there in either carts or in favorites table?

Comment: i want the list of foods which belongs to that restaurant and if the food belongs to cart or favorites i want cart_id and favorite_id for that authenticate user. if it's not there it should return cart_id and favorite_id as null.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are querying foods that belong to a restaurant AND user who added to cart OR liked it, you conditional clause in SQL is:

```
WHERE restaurant_id=:restaurant_id
    AND (carts.user_id=:user_id OR favorites.user_id=:user_id)
```

Your laravel conditional clause will then be:

```
->where('foods.restaurant_id', $request->input('restaurant_id')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('carts.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
          ->orWhere('favorites.user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})
```

Comment: i want the list of foods which belongs to that restaurant and if the food belongs to cart or favorites i want cart_id and favorite_id for that authenticate user.

Comment: I have already tried the solution you provided but it  shows cart_id and favorites_id which are in the database but not with this authenticate user. So instead of returning null it shows the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$foods = DB::table('foods')
    ->leftJoin('carts', function($join) {
        $join->on('carts.food_id', 'foods.id')
            ->where('carts.user_id', Auth::id());
    })
    ->leftJoin('favorites', function($join) {
        $join->on('favorites.food_id', 'foods.id')
            ->where('favorites.user_id', Auth::id());
    })
    ->select(...)
    ->where('foods.restaurant_id', $request->input('restaurant_id'))
    ->get();
```

BTW: You don't need `DB::raw()` for column aliases:

```
->select('carts.id as cart_id')
```